# Search SQL Server table column which has multiple leading and trailing spaces only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am selecting data from a SQL Server table which has leading space characters (could be one, two or more) and also has trailing spaces (could be one, two, and more) also.

I have used `LIKE ' %'` to search leading spaces value and used `LIKE '% '` for trailing spaces records, but the search result displayed only returns with records which has only one space as leading/trailing space. But I am not sure the number spaces available in records.

This is the query that I tried:

```
SELECT [ColumName1], [ColumName], * 
FROM [table1]  
WHERE [ColumName] LIKE ' %' OR [ColumName] LIKE '% '
```

Expected result:

```
'   Testdata1', 'Test2  ', ' Test3','     Test4 '
```

But actual result is :

```
'Test3 '
```

Comment: The result you are getting is weird. Are you sure that's leading blanks and not some other white space or control characters, such as tabs maybe?

Comment: @Zhorov - You have given condition to verify only contains space. i tried this but this giving records which has only space :(

Comment: Are you sure that, they are Spaces or Tabs?

Comment: @DineshDB - how to identify whether that is space or tab in sql column value..

Comment: Just copy a value and paste it on your note pad or somewhere else.

Comment: @Prabakaran, Try my answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @DineshDB copy pasted value to notepad++, but there is no tab, it  has only spaces

Comment: Is this really the complete query? Can you make a fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/) with your table and data, so we see what's happening?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - found the issue. data was created with ascii special characters. now issue got resolved. Thanks

Comment: Then it's even more strange that my query didn't work for you, because ASCII special characters are neither letters nor numbers. Looks like 'LIKE'  is flawed in your version. Anyway, I'm glad you found the issue.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner its not working with your query then i used CHAR(10), CHAR(13) replace logic to trim

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to do this, without using likes. `TRIM` cuts off trailing whitespaces, you can use that to filter. What you're doing here is comparing the trimmed version of every `[ColumName]` to the untrimmed version, and returning those that differ. This accomplishes what you want.

```
select 
[ColumName1], [ColumName], * 
from  [table1]  
WHERE TRIM([ColumName]) <> [ColumName]
```

This produces all fields that have any (one or more) trailing or leading whitespaces.

Depending on your version of SQL Server, `TRIM` might not be available. No matter, there's a workaround around that as well:

```
select 
[ColumName1], [ColumName], * 
from  [table1]  
WHERE LTRIM([ColumName]) <> [ColumName]
OR RTRIM([ColumName]) <> [ColumName]
```

Comment: Have tried this but now working with my data. consider in column one i have data with '<p>  <p> value </p>  </P>' and in column two i have removed <p> tag and values as '   value   ' . Your query is not returning this value :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `LTRIM` with `RTRIM` and `LIKE` operator to find spaces. Let me show an example:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
(
    FooColumn VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(' Example1'),
('  Example2'),
('Example3 '),
('Example4  '),
('Example5')

SELECT 
t.FooColumn
FROM  @tbl t  
WHERE RTRIM(t.FooColumn) LIKE '% %' OR LTRIM(t.FooColumn) LIKE '% %'
```

Comment: This particular query will return all the values which included space inbetween like 'test test test'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
DECLARE @Temp_Table TABLE 
(
    ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Temp_Table
VALUES
(' Test1'),
('  Test2'),
('Test3 '),
('Test4  '),
('Test5')

SELECT ColumnName
FROM  @Temp_Table  
WHERE (LEFT(ColumnName,1)=' ' OR RIGHT(ColumnName,1)=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, SQL Server's `LIKE` allows character sets. We can use this to find control and whitespace characters by excluding characters that we allow (letters and numbers). Please try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table1]  
WHERE [ColumName] LIKE '[^A-Za-z0-9]%' OR [ColumName] LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9]';
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found that column values has been saved with special ascii values, hence those characters were not removed while using LTRIM, RTRIM.

This worked : LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(plaincitation, CHAR(10), CHAR(32)),CHAR(13), CHAR(32)),CHAR(160), CHAR(32)),CHAR(9),CHAR(32))))